# Diagonal Stars problems

Tags: java, loops

I'm a total begginer in java and I'm having some trouble at understanding how things work... could someone explain to me why the computer understands "i" as horizontal row and "j" as vertical row since both "for" loops are the same, just with different variables?

```
public class DiagonalStar {
    public static void printSquareStar(int number) {
        if (number < 5) {
            System.out.println("Invalid Value");
        } else {
            for (int i = 1; i <= number; i++) {
                for (int j = 1; j <= number; j++) {
                    if ((i == 1) || (j == 1) || (i == number) || (j == number) || (i == j) || (j == number - i + 1)) {
                        System.out.print("*");
                    } else {
                        System.out.print(" ");
                    }
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You have one loop inside of another.  So the `j` loop will do an entire loop for every iteration of the outer `i` loop.  It may help you understand better if you print out the values of `i` and `j` each time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's actually not a matter of vertical or horizontal, is based on the order the lines of code are executed.
For example:

```
for(int n=0;n<10;n++)
{
System.out.println(n);

}
```

Would print
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9

But if you put another loop inside it, it will execute it before passing to the next loop of n.

```
for(int n=0;n<10;n++)
{
for(int m=10;m<15;m++)
{
System.out.println(n + "." + m);
}
}
```

That would print 
0.10
0.11
0.12
0.13
0.14
0.15

All that before getting to 1.10, 1.11, etc...

So when you're printing the "*" you're just looping in that logic, and whenever you complete the inner for you use println (that prints the next line)

I would suggest messing with the variables, see what the program outputs when you switch i with j or when you change the conditions.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You have nested one for loop into another. This means that for each value of `i` you are going thru all values of `j`.
After inner loop you have `System.out.println()` and this moves you to another row.

`println()` - prints text with a newline

`print()` - just prints text

Answer (score -2):

System.out.print prints in a row, while System.out.println prints in a column